# How to check if user exist in Firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase real time database, and I want to have something like this,

Location //Reference name 
------->uid //user id I will use the user uid from my SQL database not firbase push()
------->latitudeLocation
------->longitudeLocation

I use this for now to update the latitude and longitude and it work fine, but I have many user and this change only one row, I would like check first if chilled in uid is there then just keep update latitude and longitude for that user, if not there then add new user with the uid I will provide it,

```
db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getProviderDetails();


      String  uid = user.get("uid"); // here i get the uid from sqllite

googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {



                    latitudeLocation = location.getLatitude();
                    longitudeLocation = location.getLongitude();


                    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    myRef = database.getReference("Location");
                    myRef.setValue(latitudeLocation+","+longitudeLocation);


    }

        });
```

second thing when show the user location on map am using this now, this also work for single user, but I want to get all the user we add them above (eash user have different uid ) and add the to the map

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            } else {
            }
        }

        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);



        LatLng p1 = new LatLng(latitudeLocation, longitudeLocation);


        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("Location");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                String [] separated = value.split(",");
                String latPos = separated[0].trim();
                String longiPos = separated[1].trim();

                Double dlat = Double.parseDouble(latPos);
                Double dlong = Double.parseDouble(longiPos);
                drivers = new LatLng(dlat,dlong);
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(drivers).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.collection_d)));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

If can edit my code to show the new way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: anyone plzzz :(

Comment: So you want to check if a specific node is available or not?